# How does HangFire executes the methods?

Tags: c#, .net, hangfire

I've been trying to figure out how hangfire executes the enqueued jobs but I didn't manage to find an explanation anywhere. Could some please explain how does hangfire invoke the methods?

**Update:** I went through the documentation for hangfire but I didn't find any explanation on how the mechanics of hangfire works. What I am trying to understand is how hangfire is capable of invoking the methods I am passing to it.

Thanks

Comment: You want to know how it internaly works or?  Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked their official hub Acc? if not so here

http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/

an example on how it works

[image]